# Spring mvc интернационализация ошибок преобразования

Tags: spring-mvc, spring, java, интернационализация

Буду краток.

Есть контроллер, с валидацией:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
    ValidationResponse addOrder(@ModelAttribute(value = PARAM_NAME) @Valid Orders orders, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ...
}
```

При вводе на форме несуразицы вида "asda" в поля для `java.lang.Long`, получаю соответствующий `Exception` о невозможности сконвертировать из строки в число. Сообщение этого `Exception` хранится в `bindingResult`

Как можно изменить сообщение, которое при этом появляется на своё собственное, интернационализированное в соответсвии с локалью?

Что пробовал:
В конфиге spring'а есть такая штука:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>

<bean name="validator"
      class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource">
        <ref bean="messageSource"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

В `/WEB-INF/messages.properties` есть куча строк:

```
Orders.width.NotNull=Это поле не может быть пустым!
Orders.height.NotNull=Это поле не может быть пустым!
typeMismatch.java.util.Date=Должно быть коррекной датой
typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer=Должно быть корректным числом
typeMismatch.java.lang.Long=Должно быть корректным числом
java.lang.NumberFormatException=Должно быть корректным числом
typeMismatch.java.lang.NumberFormatException=Должно быть корректным числом
typeMismatch.java.lang.NumberFormat=Должно быть корректным числом
typeMismatch.orderAdd.width=Должно быть корректным числом
typeMismatch=Должно быть корректным числом
```

Но как вы наверное догадались, всё коту под хвост и нифига не резолвится. Облазил кучу сайтов, но так ответа и не нашёл.

Может кто знает, или сталкивался с этой проблемой подскажет решение?

Примечательно то, что если для поля, наример, `width` поставить проверку на Null, например так:

```
...
@NotNull(message="{Orders.width.NotNull}")
private Long width;
...
```

То сообщения проверки на `Null` резолвятся нормально. Но это никак не влияет на ошибку конвертации.

Comment: В каком конфиге Spring-а у вас определен bean `messageSource`?

Comment: В `/WEB-INF/action-servlet.xml`. А в `web.xml` есть строки:

    ...
    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>
                    /WEB-INF/action-servlet.xml
                </param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, кому интересно, я нашёл таки более-менее подходящее решение. Судя по всему если получать сообщения таким образом:

```
List<FieldError> allErrors = result.getFieldErrors();
for (FieldError objectError : allErrors) {
              objectError.getDefaultMessage();
}
```

То для большинства ошибок не используется мой `messageSource` (а действительно, с чего бы?), таким образом переводить это дело нужно почти вручную, таким вот незамысловатым способом:

```
messageSource.getMessage(objectError, locale)
```

На выходе получаем строку из `messageSource`.

Но если кто найдёт решение лучше, буду благодарен.